# AJAX not retrieving all data with javascript request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So I am using AJAX in a project for the first time and I am trying to send a `POST` but I think I am not sending the request right or there is something wrong with my syntax or mark-up.  It must be something basic because I am getting some of the request.  Check out [this test domain](http://www.kylebreitenbach.com/new_index.php).  Can anyone make any sense of how those PHP errors are playing into it?

Here is my mark-up file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

        <head>

            <title>Kyle Breitenbach - Artist Portfolio - Paintings - New York</title>

            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

            <!-- SITE CREDITS FOUND BELOW IN HUMANS.TXT -->
            <link type="text/plain" rel="author" href="humans.txt">

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=5">
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>

                function loadXMLDoc(w_year) {
                    var xmlhttp;
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }
                    else {
                        // code for IE6, IE5
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                            document.getElementById("gallery").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                        }
                    }
                    xmlhttp.open("POST","work.php",true);
                    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    xmlhttp.send("work_year="+w_year);

                }

            </script>

        </head>

        <body>

            <div id="main">

                <div id="mobileNav">
                    <div class="left">
                        <p><strong>Kyle Breitenbach</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <img alt="Kyle Breitenbach Art Gallery Icon" src="images/gallery-icon.png">
                    </div>
                    <ul id="mobileMenu">

                        <?php 
                          foreach(array_unique($w_date) as $key => $value) {
                            print("<li><a href='javascript:loadXMLDoc(" . $value . ")'>" . $value . "</a></li>" . "\n");
                          }
                        ?>

                        <li><a href="http://www.kylebreitenbach.com/cv/">CV</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.kylebreitenbach.com/contact/">Contact</a>

                    </ul><!-- "#mobileMenu -->"
                </div><!-- "#mobileNav" -->

                <div id="nav">
                  <strong>Kyle Breitenbach</strong>
                  <br><br><br>

                  <?php 
                    foreach(array_unique($w_date) as $key => $value) {
                      print("<p><a href='javascript:loadXMLDoc(" . $value . ")'>" . $value . "</a></p>" . "\n");
                    }
                  ?>

                  <br>
                  <p><a class="about" href="http://www.kylebreitenbach.com/cv/">CV</a></p>
                  <p><a class="about" href="http://www.kylebreitenbach.com/contact/">Contact</a></p>
                </div><!-- "#nav" -->

                <div id="gallery"></div>

            </div><!-- "#main" -->

            <div id="info">
                <p id="gallery-title"></p>
                <p id="gallery-medium"></p>
                <p id="gallery-size"></p>
                <p id="gallery-date"></p>
            </div><!-- "#info" -->

            <script type="text/javascript">

                $(document).ready(function() {
                    <?php print("loadXMLDoc(" . $nav_date[0] . ")"); ?>
                });

            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="new_kb.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/google-analytics.js"></script>

        </body>

    </html>
```

This is my "work.php" that the AJAX is requesting with an input for the `work_year` from the last document:

```
<?php

    require("opendbas3.php");

    $work_year = $_POST["work_year"];

    $w_query = "SELECT * FROM kb_work WHERE p_date='$work_year' ORDER BY p_id DESC";
    $w_result = mysql_query($w_query, $link);

    while ($w_row = mysql_fetch_array($w_result)) {

        $w_id = array();        $w_id_str = $w_row["p_id"];         array_push($w_id, $w_id_str);
        $w_src = array();       $w_src_str = $w_row["p_src"];       array_push($w_src, $w_src_str);
        $w_title = array();     $w_title_str = $w_row["p_title"];   array_push($w_title, $w_title_str);
        $w_medium = array();    $w_medium_str = $w_row["p_medium"]; array_push($w_medium, $w_medium_str);
        $w_size = array();      $w_size_str = $w_row["p_size"];     array_push($w_size, $w_size_str);
        $w_date = array();      $w_date_str = $w_row["p_date"];     array_push($w_date, $w_date_str);

    }

    print('<div id="gallery-control-bar">');
        print('<div id="gallery-buttons" class="control-bar-item">');
            print('<div id="previous-button" class="gallery-button">&larr;</div>');
            print('<div id="next-button" class="gallery-button">&rarr;</div>');
        print('</div><!-- "#gallery-buttons" -->');
        print('<div id="image-index" class="control-bar-item"><span id="current-post"></span> of <span id="post-total"></span></div>');
        print('<div id="gallery-type" class="control-bar-item">');
            print('<img id="gallery-switch" alt="Kyle Breitenbach Art Gallery Icon" src="images/gallery-icon.png"');
        print('</div><!-- "#gallery-type -->');
    print('</div><!-- "#gallery-control-bar" -->');

    print('<div id="gallery-image"></div>');
    print("<div id='gallery-viewer'>");

        foreach($w_id as $key => $value) {
            print("<div class='gallery-row'>");

            $i = 1;
            for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($w_id); $x++) {
                print("<img id='" . $x . "' class='gallery-item' src='" . $w_src[$x] . "' alt='Kyle Breitenbach " . $w_title[$x] . "'>");
                if (($i % 4) == 0) {
                    print("</div><div class='gallery-row'>");
                }
                $i++;
            } 

            print("</div>");

        }

    print('</div><!-- "#gallery-viewer" -->');

    print("<script type='text/javascript'>");

        print("var w_id = " . json_encode($w_id));
        print("var w_src = " . json_encode($w_src));
        print("var w_title = " . json_encode($w_title));
        print("var w_medium = " . json_encode($w_medium));
        print("var w_size = " . json_encode($w_size));
        print("var w_date = " . json_encode($w_date));

    print("</script>");

?>
```

And this is the JS file that ties the effects together, this stuff might be a little irrelevant:

```
        var currentImg = 0;
        var totalImg = 0;

        $("#next-button").click(function() {
            if (currentImg == totalImg) {
                currentImg = 0;
            }
            else {
                currentImg++;
            }
            changeImg();
        });

        $("#previous-button").click(function() {
            if (currentImg == 0) {
                currentImg = totalImg;
            }
            else {
                currentImg--;
            }
            changeImg();
        });

        function changeImg() {

            $("#gallery-image").html("<img src='" + w_src[currentImg] + "'>");
            $("#gallery-title").html(w_title[currentImg]);
            $("#gallery-medium").html(w_medium[currentImg]);
            $("#gallery-size").html(w_size[currentImg]);
            $("#gallery-date").html(w_date[currentImg]);

            var userCurrent = currentImg + 1;
            var userTotal = galleryYear.x_id.length;

            $("#current-post").html(userCurrent);
            $("#post-total").html(userTotal);

            var galWidth = $("#gallery-image" > "img").width();
            $("#gallery").width(galWidth);

        }
```

Do you have any ideas on how I can either re-approach AJAX with maybe a different configuration of calling the function?  Maybe something that would better suit the nature of my request to make it work properly?

Comment: The script providing your AJAX results **should not** be formatting anything, it should be returning a nice data set which the requester will then format. You should reevaluate the way this works.

Comment: From the errors, it appears that $w_date is undefined. try setting a hard value for that and see if it corrects it. If it does, figure out why your var is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you have 3 separate errors:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: w_date in /hermes/bosoraweb186/b1303/ipg.joshiefishbeincom/kyle-breitenbach/new_index.php on line 95 


Warning: array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /hermes/bosoraweb186/b1303/ipg.joshiefishbeincom/kyle-breitenbach/new_index.php on line 95 


Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /hermes/bosoraweb186/b1303/ipg.joshiefishbeincom/kyle-breitenbach/new_index.php on line 95
```

They all three come from this line and it's all related to the same problem.

```
foreach(array_unique($w_date) as $key => $value) {
```

1. `$wdate` is not defined.
2. You are trying to run `array_unique` on an undefined variable
3. You are then trying to loop through an the array you attempted to create with `array_unique`

Basically, you just need to make sure that `$wdate` is being set and that it is an array.